# lookup function that takes the first populated cell as opposed to the first cell

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup

I want to do a lookup on our customer database to bring back any email addresses we have for customers that belong to a specific account number.

Our database is set up so that there are accounts and each account has its own individual acc no. Within the accounts there can be any number of contacts and for each contact there may be an email address. I can download a list of contact details that contains all contacts for all accounts. This results in an excel doc where the account no's will be seen as many times as there are contacts for that account.

I have been able to do a VLOOKUP to return some email addresses but because some of the contacts do not have email addresses, and these contacts are at the top of the list/column so to speak, I am getting blanks where there are contacts for those accounts that have email address details.

In short, I need a function that will perform the VLOOKUP process but will not just take the first cell value that corresponds with the specific acc no. I need it to continue searching for the same account number until it finds a row that contains an email address.

I would really appreciate any help that anyone is kind enough to provide.

Thanks

Barney

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not sure I fully understand the structure of your worksheet(s), but suggest a PivotTable might be useful in this context:

[image: SO20701989 example]